# Adding Graphics (paint) to a pre-existing JPanel

Tags: java, paint

I am trying to add graphics (paint) to a JPanel that is located on a JFrame.  Both of these (Panel and Frame) have all ready been created in a separate class. I can not get the paint method to work correctly. Any ideas?

```
public class SeeProgressHandleClass extends JPanel implements MouseListener{

  JFrame window;
  JPanel panel;
  Graph graph;

  public SeeProgressHandleClass(JFrame window) {
    this.window = window;
  }

  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    panel = new JPanel();

    fillPanel();

    window.add(panel);
    panel.setBackground(Color.white);       
    panel.setBounds(50, 40, 1100, 660);     
  }

  public static void fillPanel() {
    //These three methods just add Labels and other panels to the panel
    addExitBox();
    addTitle();
    addLabels();        

    graph = new Graph(panel);
  }
}

public class Graph extends JPanel{

  public Graph(JPanel panel){
    panel.repaint();
  }

  public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(Color.green);
    g.fillOval(100,100,100,100);
  }
}
```

Comment: Read through the tutorial, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/ you need some fundamentals. Just delete this code and start from scratch.

Comment: Sorry actually start with the basic swing gui tutorial. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/start/index.html